# How can you output Error messages to a different logfile?

Tags: perl, logging, stderr

In Perl you can:

```
print STDERR "bla bla bla";
```

...and Apache will dump it to `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log`.

But what if I want to send **some** error/warning messages to a different log file?

How can I create a function to do this in Perl?

```
print MYLOGFILE "bla bla bla"
```

...to render to `/logs/my_favorite_log`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Log::Trivial](http://search.cpan.org/~atrickett/Log-Trivial-0.31/lib/Log/Trivial.pm#set_log_level)

```
use Log::Trivial;
my $logfile = Log::Trivial->new(log_file => "logs/my_favourite.log");
$logfile->set_level(3);
$logfile->write(comment => "bla bla bla");
```

Answer (score 7):

You should probably take a look at some of the formal logging packages for Perl, like [log4perl](http://mschilli.github.com/log4perl/). Undoubtedly, there are others as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend looking at [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Log%3a%3aLog4perl), as suggested by Will. There is good [introduction tutorial available](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/09/11/log4perl.html).

For small scripts there is also quick setup with [easy mode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Log%3a%3aLog4perl#Easy_Mode).